# How to find a value in a nested array of objects and update it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying find a value in a nested array of objects and updated it. More specifically, in the array below, I am trying to find the `OptionCode` based on a String and set the corresponding option to `blocked`. The search strings are stored in an array.

**Inital Array:**

```
filters: [
    {
        FilterCode: "TourPrice",
        FilterName: "Tour Price",
        FilterIcon: show_Dollar,
        Options: [
            {
                Name: "Free",
                OptionCode: "Free",
                active: false,
                blocked: false,
                forbiddenFilterOptionCode: ["LowestPrice"],
            },
            {
                Name: "Paid",
                OptionCode: "Paid",
                active: false,
                blocked: false,
                forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],
            },
            {
                Name: "Free and Paid",
                OptionCode: "FreeAndPaid",
                active: true,
                blocked: false,
                forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        FilterCode: "SortedBy",
        FilterName: "Sorted By",
        FilterIcon: show_Sort,
        Options: [
            {
                Name: "Most Relevant",
                OptionCode: "MostRelevant",
                active: true,
                blocked: false,
                forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],
            },
            {
                Name: "Latest Tour",
                OptionCode: "LatestTour",
                active: false,
                blocked: false,
                forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],
            },
            {
                Name: "Oldest Tour",
                OptionCode: "OldestTour",
                active: false,
                blocked: false,
                forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],
            },
            {
                Name: "Lowest Price",
                OptionCode: "LowestPrice",
                active: false,
                blocked: false,
                forbiddenFilterOptionCode: ["Free", "FreeAndPaid],
            },
        ],
    },
],
```

For the following search input `["Free", "FreeAndPaid"]` the following array is expected.

**Intended Result Array**

```
filters: [
    {
        FilterCode: "TourPrice",
        FilterName: "Tour Price",
        FilterIcon: show_Dollar,
        Options: [
            {
                Name: "Free",
                OptionCode: "Free", // Find OptionCode
                active: false,
                blocked: true, // set blocked to true
                forbiddenFilterOptionCode: ["LowestPrice"],
            },
            {
                Name: "Paid",
                OptionCode: "Paid",
                active: false,
                blocked: false,
                forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],
            },
            {
                Name: "Free and Paid",
                OptionCode: "FreeAndPaid", // Find OptionCode
                active: true,
                blocked: true, // set blocked to true
                forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        FilterCode: "SortedBy",
        FilterName: "Sorted By",
        FilterIcon: show_Sort,
        Options: [
            {
                Name: "Most Relevant",
                OptionCode: "MostRelevant",
                active: true,
                blocked: false,
                forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],
            },
            {
                Name: "Latest Tour",
                OptionCode: "LatestTour",
                active: false,
                blocked: false,
                forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],
            },
            {
                Name: "Oldest Tour",
                OptionCode: "OldestTour",
                active: false,
                blocked: false,
                forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],
            },
            {
                Name: "Lowest Price",
                OptionCode: "LowestPrice",
                active: false,
                blocked: false,
                forbiddenFilterOptionCode:  ["Free", "FreeAndPaid"],
            },
        ],
    },
],
```

Comment: Is it intended that in the very last property, the string `"FreeAndPaid"`  is removed from the result? If so, why? Also note a missing double quote in the original data structure at that spot.

Comment: @trincot thank you. No it is not intended. I updated the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the function below. I made `filters` a variable, as it is not clear from your question what object it is a property of.

The solution is to iterate the array, then iterate the option objects, and finally detect whether that object's  OptionCode value is among your targeted values.

The `filters` structure is thus modified *in place*:

```js
function setBlocked(filters, target) {
    for (let filter of filters) {
        for (let option of filter.Options) {
            if (target.includes(option.OptionCode)) {
                option.blocked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

let filters = [{FilterCode: "TourPrice",FilterName: "Tour Price",FilterIcon: "show_Dollar",Options: [{Name: "Free",OptionCode: "Free",active: false,blocked: false,forbiddenFilterOptionCode: ["LowestPrice"],},{Name: "Paid",OptionCode: "Paid",active: false,blocked: false,forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],},{Name: "Free and Paid",OptionCode: "FreeAndPaid",active: true,blocked: false,forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],},],},{FilterCode: "SortedBy",FilterName: "Sorted By",FilterIcon: "show_Sort",Options: [{Name: "Most Relevant",OptionCode: "MostRelevant",active: true,blocked: false,forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],},{Name: "Latest Tour",OptionCode: "LatestTour",active: false,blocked: false,forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],},{Name: "Oldest Tour",OptionCode: "OldestTour",active: false,blocked: false,forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],},{Name: "Lowest Price",OptionCode: "LowestPrice",active: false,blocked: false,forbiddenFilterOptionCode: ["Free", "FreeAndPaid"],},],},];

setBlocked(filters, ["Free", "FreeAndPaid"]);

console.log(filters);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const filters = [
  {
    FilterCode: "TourPrice",
    FilterName: "Tour Price",
    FilterIcon: null,
    Options: [
      {
        Name: "Free",
        OptionCode: "Free",
        active: false,
        blocked: false,
        forbiddenFilterOptionCode: ["LowestPrice"],
      },
      {
        Name: "Paid",
        OptionCode: "Paid",
        active: false,
        blocked: false,
        forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],
      },
      {
        Name: "Free and Paid",
        OptionCode: "FreeAndPaid",
        active: true,
        blocked: false,
        forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    FilterCode: "SortedBy",
    FilterName: "Sorted By",
    FilterIcon: null,
    Options: [
      {
        Name: "Most Relevant",
        OptionCode: "MostRelevant",
        active: true,
        blocked: false,
        forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],
      },
      {
        Name: "Latest Tour",
        OptionCode: "LatestTour",
        active: false,
        blocked: false,
        forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],
      },
      {
        Name: "Oldest Tour",
        OptionCode: "OldestTour",
        active: false,
        blocked: false,
        forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [],
      },
      {
        Name: "Lowest Price",
        OptionCode: "LowestPrice",
        active: false,
        blocked: false,
        forbiddenFilterOptionCode: ["Free", "FreeAndPaid"],
      },
    ],
  },
];
optionsToSearch = ["Free", "FreeAndPaid"];
const newFilters = filters.map((filter) => {
  const options = filter.Options.map((option) => {
    if (optionsToSearch.includes(option.OptionCode)) {
      return { ...option, blocked: true };
    } else {
      return option;
    }
  });
  return { ...filter, Options: options };
});

console.log(newFilters);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a new array of objects, you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on your `filters` array, where you map each object a new object containing all the properties it original had (done using the [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)), but overwrite the `Options` key with a newly mapped array. To map this array, you can build a new object from the take the properties/values from each option object (again using the spread syntax), and overwrite the `blocked` property based on whether the search array contains your `OptionCode` from the current option object:

```js
const filters = [{ FilterCode: "TourPrice", FilterName: "Tour Price", FilterIcon: 'show_Dollar', Options: [{ Name: "Free", OptionCode: "Free", active: false, blocked: false, forbiddenFilterOptionCode: ["LowestPrice"], }, { Name: "Paid", OptionCode: "Paid", active: false, blocked: false, forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [], }, { Name: "Free and Paid", OptionCode: "FreeAndPaid", active: true, blocked: false, forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [], }, ], }, { FilterCode: "SortedBy", FilterName: "Sorted By", FilterIcon: "show_Sort", Options: [{ Name: "Most Relevant", OptionCode: "MostRelevant", active: true, blocked: false, forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [], }, { Name: "Latest Tour", OptionCode: "LatestTour", active: false, blocked: false, forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [], }, { Name: "Oldest Tour", OptionCode: "OldestTour", active: false, blocked: false, forbiddenFilterOptionCode: [], }, { Name: "Lowest Price", OptionCode: "LowestPrice", active: false, blocked: false, forbiddenFilterOptionCode: ["Free", "FreeAndPaid"], }, ], } ];

const search = ["Free", "FreeAndPaid"];
const result = filters.map(obj => ({
  ...obj,
  Options: obj.Options.map(option => ({
    ...option,
    blocked: search.includes(option.OptionCode)
  }))
}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by mapping `Options` inside `filters` then checking tge search terms with `includes`:

```js
const terms = ['Free']
const result = filters.map(f => {
  return {
    ...f
    Options: f.Options.map(o => {
      if (terms.includes(o.Name)) {
        return {
          ...o,
          blocked: true,
        }
       }
       return o
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getIndizesForPropValue = (propValue, list) => {
    return list
        .reduce((acc, curr, i) =>  [...acc, [i, curr.Options.findIndex((o) => o.OptionCode === propValue)]], [])
        .find((x) => x[1] >= 0)
};

const idx = getIndizesForPropValue('Free', filters);
filters[idx[0]].Options[idx[1]].OptionCode = 'NewValue'
```